# Send and receive string values via bluetooth android

Tags: android, string, bluetooth, send

I'm developing an app where I need to send 3 seekbar's values to a PCB via bluetooth. I've done all the bluetooth code based on the bluetoothchat example. I first modified it to send a string with these 3 values. But now, I need to do something more dificult and i don't know how to do it.

First of all, in the app i modify the seekbars and then i click on the send button. In the code, I need to set a string for each seekbar's value, because I need to access to the MCU variables and set each variable address, value, CRC etc...

So, I need to know the correct way to do this. Here is the code where i define the send function:

```
/**
 * SEND THREAD
 */
/**[Start Thread + Send command + Nº bytes thread + Nº bytes variable + Address + Variable value + CRC]*/

public void sendValues() {

    /**Set the seekbars values into a string*/
    send_value1 = Integer.toString(savedProgress1);
    send_value2 = Integer.toString(savedProgress2);
    send_value3 = Integer.toString(savedProgress3);



    String message1 = start_thread+" "+send_command+" "+num_byte_trama1+ " "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_1+" "+Value+" "+CRC;
    String message2 = start_thread+" "+send_command+" "+num_byte_trama1+ " "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_2+" "+Value+" "+CRC;
    String message3 = start_thread+" "+send_command+" "+num_byte_trama1+ " "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_3+" "+Value+" "+CRC;
    String message4 = start_thread+" "+send_command+" "+num_byte_trama2+ " "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_save_request+" "+Value+" "+CRC;
    String message5 = start_thread+" "+send_command+" "+num_byte_trama2+ " "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_save_status+" "+Value+" "+CRC;



    /**Check that we're actually connected before trying anything*/
    if (GlobalVar.mTransmission.getState() != GlobalVar.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    /**Get the message bytes and tell the Transmission to write*/
    byte[] send = message.getBytes();
    GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send);

    /**Reset out string buffer to zero*/
    GlobalVar.mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
}
```

There are these few things that I ask you to help me:

```
1- Need to know how to calculate the CRC
2- I need to send these 5 strings together when pressing the send button.
```

In the part where i get the bytes to send, I don't know If the right way to do this would be to add these 5 strings on 1 and send this one (maybe it would be to long if I do this), or to create a function to send these 5 separately but at the same time.

This is the edited code to send each message one by one:

```
    /**Conversion to decimal of the seekbar's % value*/
    send_int1 = ((savedProgress1 * 20480) / 100) * -1;
    send_int2 = ((savedProgress2 * 20480) / 100) * -1;
    send_int3 = ((savedProgress3 * 20480) / 100) * -1;

    /**Conversion to string of the previous values to send in the string message*/
    sendValue1 = Integer.toString(send_int1);
    sendValue2 = Integer.toString(send_int1);
    sendValue3 = Integer.toString(send_int1);


    String message1 = start_thread+" "+send_command+" "+num_byte_trama1+" "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_1+" "+sendValue1+" " ;
    String message2 = start_thread+" "+send_command+" "+num_byte_trama1+" "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_2+" "+sendValue2+" " ;
    String message3 = start_thread+" "+send_command+" "+num_byte_trama1+" "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_3+" "+sendValue3+" " ;
    String message4 = start_thread+" "+send_command+" "+num_byte_trama2+" "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_save_request+" " ;
    String message5 = start_thread+" "+send_command+" "+num_byte_trama2+" "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_save_status+" " ;



    /**Check that we're actually connected before trying anything*/
    if (GlobalVar.mTransmission.getState() != GlobalVar.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    /**Get the message bytes and tell the Transmission to write*/
    byte[] send1 = message1.getBytes();
    GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send1);

    //Wait untill I receive the confirmation from the MCU

    byte[] send2 = message2.getBytes();
    GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send2);

    byte[] send3 = message3.getBytes();
    GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send3);

    byte[] send4 = message4.getBytes();
    GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send4);

    byte[] send5 = message5.getBytes();
    GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send5);


    /**Reset out string buffer to zero*/
    GlobalVar.mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
}
```

Comment: What kind of CRC it is ?
If you want to send all the data in the same frame, you can juste do `String stringToSend = message1+message2+message3+message4+message5`
but I don't think it's the greatest idea. 
When I have to send bluetooth frame, I prefer use a header, like `11AA`, then send the frame length, and then the frame content. with that, it will be easier for you to catch a new frame.

Comment: I'm thinking about sending each message one by one. I send the first, i wait untill I receive the confirmation and then send the next. The CRC that I need to calculate is for this variables: {send_comand, num_byte_trama, num_byte_variable, pos_reg, value}. So, I need to create a function, that calculates the CRC of these variables for each message. Some help please.

Comment: Yeah, but which kind of CRC it is ? 16 ? 32 ?

Answer (score 1):

For your frame, I recommand you to use this kind of frame :

`final byte[] HEADER = AA11 // For example
// When you want to send a message :
Strign messageToSend = new String(HEADER) + yourStringMessage`

It'll be easier for you to analyze the frame when you receive it.

Then, for the CRC, I can't answer if you don't tell the kind of CRC. In my app, I used

```
private static char createCRC(byte[] frame)
{ 
    int crc = 0;
    for(byte i : frame)
    {
        crc = crc^i;
    }
   return (char)crc;
}
```

to create the CRC by "XORing" each byte of my message , and then check a CRC is quite easy

UPDATE : Well, I finally get it.

In the BluetoothChat activity, you get a string version of message, and the byte[] one.
If you want to get the first byte of the message, just add `byte myByte = readBuf[0]` before `String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);`
Then, `String readMessage = new String(myByte, 0, msg.arg1);`

Comment: I really don't know much about how to calculate the CRC or what kind of CRC I need. I'm just started on programming with this project on android. My partner that has made the MCU's software doesn't know what kind of CRC he is calculating. He just says me that I have to sum those variable's bytes and then convert to hex. About the string message sending, I appreciate your suggestion, but I'm not shure how to do it, so i will try with my method first. The thing that I want to ask you is:

Comment: When I send the message1 for example, the MCU sends me a response. I need to know how to get this response and read it, it wil be something like {2b 00 00} and the middle 00 is what I need to confirm that it has been sent right and to continue sendind the message2. Im using the bluetoohchat example's code modified for this purpouse, but i don't find where is reading to get the response variable

Comment: In the aceptThread there is this code: _// Read from the InputStream_
                    `bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);`

                    _// Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity_
                    `mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();`    But i don't know where it goes.

Comment: In the connectedThread, if your code is based on BluetoothChat.
mHandler send the message to the UI

Comment: True, thanks. I see that this is the message `mConversationArrayAdapter.add(readMessage);` So, in my code, how can I introduce this value and split it to get the 00 value from the resulting string {2b 00 00} ??

Comment: Well, You can handle it in the ConnectedThread, or directly in the activity (not recommanded, because of bluetooth on the Main thread).

In the ConnectedThread,, there is a `while(true)` loop, just put your code here.

Comment: Ok. But what I mean is, to get the read message if I'm right, I have to get the readMessage variable, and split it to get the desire value. How can i split it and get it?

Comment: If you message is a byte[] :
`for(byte i : readMessage) { /*Do what you want*/}` but I'm not sure to understand what you want to do without your code :/

Comment: Well, I've got the bluetooth code where instead of having a chat communication like in the bluetoothChat example, I need to send 3 seekbar's values between 0 and 100 to a other PCB's MCU via bluetooth. But instead of sending only this 3 values, I have to access to the MCU's variables and then write there the values. So, the 5 string messages in the code above, send the thread to access to the variables and write the value. What I need is after sending each message, read the MCU's response to verify that I have sent it right. I've inserted a comment on the code where I need this function

Comment: the response that the MCU sends to me after a write is like: {start_thread OK CRC} and in values {2b 00 00} so I need to split this message to get the middle 00 that indicates that the communication has been made ok and that I can continue to send the second string. And continue like this until I send the 5 messages